# Reading IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY to find exported function names causes access violation

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable

I am reading IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY as follows

```
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY ExportDirectory = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((DWORD)dosHeader + ConvertRVA(PEImageOptionalHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress,
        FirstSectionHeader,PEFileImageHeader));
```

This works.Then i want to access `AddressOfNames`.

```
PDWORD* ExportedFunctions;
ExportedFunctions = (PDWORD *)((DWORD)dosHeader + ConvertRVA(ExportDirectory->AddressOfNames,FirstSectionHeader,PEFileImageHeader));
```

Now how can i find the names of the exported functions?`ConvertRVA()` is defined as

```
DWORD ConvertRVA(DWORD rva,PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER FirstSectionHeader,PIMAGE_FILE_HEADER PEFileImageHeader)
{
    int j=0;
    auto i =FirstSectionHeader;
    for(;j<PEFileImageHeader->NumberOfSections ;i++,j++)
    {
        if(rva>=i->VirtualAddress && rva<i->VirtualAddress + i->Misc.VirtualSize)
            break;
    }
    return rva+i->PointerToRawData-i->VirtualAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

```
 PDWORD ExportedFunctions;
    ExportedFunctions = (PDWORD )((DWORD)dosHeader + ConvertRVA(ExportDirectory->AddressOfNames,FirstSectionHeaderBest,PEFileImageHeader));



    for(int i=0;i<ExportDirectory->NumberOfNames;i++)
    {
        LPSTR aaaa=(PCHAR)((DWORD)dosHeader + ConvertRVA((DWORD)ExportedFunctions[0],FirstSectionHeaderBest,PEFileImageHeader)); 
        std::cout<<aaaa<<std::endl;
    }
```